# MacOS: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

```
!python {'/content/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {'/content/Training'} -l {'/content/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
!python {'/content/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{'/content/Testing'} -l {'/content/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}
```

running which gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/generate_tfrecord.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/generate_tfrecord.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
```

MacOS Catalina 10.15.2, Tensorflow (latest version)

I have already installed all dependencies through pip. (object-detection api, exported the path in terminal, ran the command "python setup.py install in the same path)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have compiled the proto files right.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<PATH_TO_TF>/TensorFlow/models/research
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<PATH_TO_TF>/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<PATH_TO_TF>/TensorFlow/models/research/slim
```

After exporting, inside `tensorflow/models/research` you can run

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

It will work. I have tested it out on my mac os before.

Comment: Hey Sahu, I have tried your steps, but it still shows the same error.

Comment: Can you go over this link and check once https://towardsdatascience.com/training-tensorflow-object-detection-api-with-custom-dataset-for-working-in-javascript-and-vue-js-6634e0f33e03

Comment: Have you tried running a python script from a file and try to import `from object_detection.utils import dataset_util`? Then maybe do an explicit path  `sys.path.append(local_module_dir)`. That may help isolate the issue.